# React app 'Failed to compile' because './node_modules/jss-default-unit/lib/index.js' not found

Tags: reactjs

I've just updated some Node modules in a React react project, but now when I go to `localhost:3000` I get a `Failed to compile` error because `./node_modules/jss-default-unit/lib/index.js` was not found:

[image]

The packages I've upgraded are Material UI and `react-scripts`, as seen from a `git diff` of `package.json`:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

(This issue, https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss/issues/146, describes a similar issue caused by Babel running on `node_modules`, but I wasn't able to find a `webpack.config.js` in `node_modules/babel-loader` to modify).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by running `npm install jss-default-unit` and restarting the server with `npm start`.